# Allow us time to [do something] by [deadline]

Tags: grammar

Recently I came across this sentence:

> "Please let us know if you are prepared to allow us time to file his
>   [document] by 1 Jan 2015"

It feels wrong to me but I would like to know if this may be correct in anyway because I would think that you either say: (a) "allow us time to prepare..." OR (b) "allow us to file by 1 Jan 2015"; or even "allow us time... with the deadline of 1 Jan 2015"

My logic is this: (a) refers to a block/period of time by itself already and I would treat it as a kind of THING. To add the qualifier "by 1 Jan 2015" would then not make sense. I am pretty sure the sentence could be phrased much more elegantly but my main question is, is it even correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mostly correct.

We'd normally say (in AmE) (a)...allow us 3 weeks to file his [document]. or (b)...allow us to file his [document] by January 1.

> Please let us know if you are prepared to allow us time to file his [document] by 1 Jan 2015.

I think the only time I'd use that construction is if I were busy with other projects and needed to let my supervisor know that I would have to sacrifice time on those projects to get this new document filed by the January 1 deadline.

> Boss: Here's a new file for you. Deadline is January 1.
>
> Me: Alright, but I'm pretty busy. *Are you prepared to allow me time to file his [document] by 1 Jan 2015?* It's either that, or pay for overtime.
>
> Boss: Make this your top priority! Everything else can wait.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the writer actually meant "Please let us know by 1 Jan 2015 if [i.e., whether] you are prepared to allow us [the additional] time [we requested] to file his [document]."  but simply misplaced the phrase "by 1 Jan 2015"   —  not realizing that it completely changes the meaning and leads to misunderstanding?

Comment: Ooohhh, I hadn't considered that. Good catch!

Comment: you are right! (Given the context of the sentence I know this is not what the author meant) but I've never thought of that too!